# onBackPressed android handling

Tags: android, overriding, back-button

I want to do something on back button pressed. I read that there is a method onBackPressed. I used this method but now I can't close my application with the back button.
Here my code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mViewpager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mylaout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After you've done your stuff, just call `super`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mViewpager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mylaout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the method of the `super` class when you want to close. Set `shouldClose` (member variable in your activity, that you have declare on your own) to true if the back button should close the app, false otherwise.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(shouldClose){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else {
        mViewpager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mylaout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```